# How to solve the overlapping when appending number with two table or element?

Tags: jquery, html

When you click on the button from both table randomly,the number will not following sequence on it own table.This is a main issue on my question.Thank. 
This is HTML code:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_4" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_5" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

This is Jquery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num+=1;
            $("#project,textarea").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });

$("#pub_addbtn").click(function(){
    var val=parseInt($("#pub tr:last").text());
        val+=1; 
            $("#pub,textarea").append("<tr><td>"+val+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });
```

});

Sorry another table is here:

```
<table width="600px" id="pub">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pub_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pub_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pub_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><textarea name="pub_4" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><textarea name="pub_5" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="button" name="pub_addbtn" value="ADD" id="pub_addbtn">
```

Comment: Why are you appending to `textarea`? That adds the HTML to every `textarea` element on the page. You should just be appending to `#project`.

Comment: I feel there are few lines of code missing. I cannot see #pub_addbtn button in the DOM.

Comment: if the textarea is eliminated,it will not work.But the main issue is the number appended not follow the sequence.

Comment: Who suggested removing the textarea? I just asked why you're appending to it. What did you mean when you wrote `$("#project,textarea").append()`?

Comment: ok,if i just put '$("#project").append();' ,it's work thank.Sorry for my big mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)... and have fixed some of your selectors. **http://jsfiddle.net/yHKrt/**

Assuming you have 2 tables and 2 buttons there were issues with the code which caused this issue. This code fixes it.

```
$("#addbtn").click(function () {

    var num = parseInt($("#project tr:last").index()) + 1;
    num += 1;
    $("#project").append("<tr><td>" + num + "</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
});

$("#pub_addbtn").click(function () {

    var val = parseInt($("#pub tr:last").index()) + 1;
    val += 1;
    $("#pub").append("<tr><td>" + val + "</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: I'm a beginner for stackoverflow,how to demo coding in fiddle or the link that you post?

Comment: First of all welcome to SO. Go to jsfiddle.net put your html, javascript, css in appropriate columns Run it.. Thats it.. :) then flick on Fork and share the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#project").children("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ',textarea' from the selectors. It should be:

```
$("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
```

You were appending the `<tr>` to every `<textarea>` element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/JWG68/

## JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addbtn").click(function () {
        var num = parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num += 1;
        $("#project").append("<tr><td>" + num + "</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
    });
    $("#pub_addbtn").click(function () {
        var val = parseInt($("#pub tr:last").text());
        val += 1;
        $("#pub").append("<tr><td>"+val+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num = parseInt($("#project tr:last td:first").text(), 10) + 1;
    $("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/e3ddy/

Changes:

1. It specifically targets the first column of the last row and gets just the text from that.
2. It only appends to the table, not to the textarea.
3. It specifies the radix for `parseInt()` which is desired for reliability.

You can make similar changes for the other button's code.

Comment: That's the radix argument to `parseInt()`, telling it to use base 10.

Comment: @JCChan - you should always pass the second argument to `parseInt()` which tells it what number base to use (base 10 in this case) because without that, it will guess based on the input which is a bad idea (sometimes it will choose hex or octal).  See the [`parseInt` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: can you give me a more reference to improve `my` skills in **Jquery** online?

Comment: @JCChan - search for "learn jquery" on Google.  Lots of choices.  Since you're new here, are you aware of the proper procedure here on StackOverflow when someone answers your question (select best answer and click the green checkmark to the left of the answer - this will earn you some reputation points and reward the person who supplied the answer)?